# roo gem can not work(NameError: uninitialized constant Excel)

Tags: ruby, excel

I run the following code in irb:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
=> false
irb(main):002:0> require 'roo'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> s = Excel.new("/Users/tangmonk/Desktop/zhongshikehua/import.xls")
NameError: uninitialized constant Excel
```

I tried to contact the gem author, but I got no reply.

I just want to read an excel file, if this gem does not work well, Can someone recommend other gem.

Comment: You don't need to require `"rubygems"` unless you are using a very old Ruby. In fact, the return value being `false` means it has no effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the code as below :

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'roo'

Roo::Excel.new("/Users/tangmonk/Desktop/zhongshikehua/import.xls")
```

Look at the Documentation - [Usage](https://github.com/Empact/roo#usage) and also look at this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/hmcgowan/roo/issues/19).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I try your code, It not throw any error. But It very slow to open xls file. actually not completed until now. this xls file about 800kb, I spend 15s to open it when I use OpenOffice.

Comment: @user3160143 That I can't answer you..May be you can tell [here](https://github.com/Empact/roo/issues)

Comment: I am sorry, When I seach "roo" with github, this **"hmcgowan/roo"** repo on the first, So I I mistakenly thought that this is the official gem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Arup nailed it . I came across the same issue while using roo to convert xls to csv.

`error` I was getting before adding ....Roo::Excel.....

```
': uninitialized constant Excel (NameError)
    from rooxls2csv.rb:7:in `glob'
```

Working code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'roo'

pwd       = File.dirname(__FILE__)

Dir.glob("#{pwd}/*.xls") do |file|
  file_path = "#{pwd}/#{file}"
  file_basename = File.basename(file, ".xls")
  xls =Roo::Excel.new(file_path)
  xls.to_csv("#{pwd}/#{file_basename}.csv")
end
```